# Can we start a blog for parenting.SE?

Tags: discussion

I have seen many sites have their own blogs which regularly publish about the site's activities and other stuff.

Do we want to start a blog for **parenting.SE**?

As highlighted on the [Blogoverflow introduction](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/):

> Starting a blog is easy.  Keeping up a blog, contributing to it regularly is difficult.  Blogs are hard work.  Wanting a blog is obviously the first step, but there are a few things that the community needs to discuss in order to get a blog going.

According to that post, there are 4 things we need to do:

1. Raise the idea on the child meta. A community blog needs the involvement of community members.  These blogs don’t exist to be the personal blog of a community member.  They are both for and run by the community.  It needs to be something the community collectively wants and will cultivate.
2. Define the scope and purpose of the blog. Is the blog about the site? Is it about the site’s topic? Is it about the industry around the topic? Keep in mind the audience of your community and their interests. Another generic blog about  may not be all that interesting.  A community blog should be interesting to both current members and potential new members.
3. Recruit contributors. Who will write entries for the blog? Starting a blog is a bit like going through the buffet line. Be realistic – don’t let your eyes be bigger than your stomach. Think seriously about if and how often you will be able to contribute a blog post, including research/prep time.  The more contributors there are, the less frequently each contributor needs to post.  One post a month is a much easier to stomach than a couple posts every week.
4. Plan a schedule. Given the results of steps #2 and #3, think about a rough idea of a schedule for the blog. Will there be one post a week, posted Mondays? Will there be  posts on Tuesdays and  posts on Fridays? You don’t need to be pushing out posts daily, but you should post at least once a week.

Please post answers if you have suggestions/opinions/feedback for any of the 4 items.  Also answer if you are willing to participate by writing blog entries as defined by whatever scope and purpose we agree upon, with an indication of how much you expect to be able to participate (e.g. "I can write one or two blog posts", "I can commit to a single post every month", etc.).

Please upvote the question if you want to see a blog.  Please upvote individual answers if you agree with the points made.

After we've had time for people to answer, comment, and vote, we'll review this and determine whether there is enough interest and participation to move forward with a community blog.

Comment: I've edited the question to invite open community discussion as to whether there is overall interest in a blog, and if we have enough commitment to make it work.

Comment: we can keep the active blog by posting question of the week which help us them to stay tuned about the block contents for atleast 5 months we have lots of content in our parent.se so we can post it and start te blog

Comment: Posting a "question of the week" is something better suited towards the SE twitter and Google+ feeds. From the link to blogoverflow I cited, regarding highlighting top content: "What great question was posted on the site recently?  Recognize it!  Don’t just copy the question and its answers to the blog, blog about the question and its answers.  A fine line there, eh?  Delve deeper into the question or an answer.  Add more context.  Compare or analyze answers against each other.  There is a lot to work with here."

Comment: While I'm always happy to see that a community wants to start a blog, I must bring up two concerns: (1) This site has, historically, not really had the kind of community involvement I would expect in order to see a blog atmosphere thriving, and (2) How useful would a blog be given that this site is essentially the test case for *Good Subjective, Bad Subjective* ? In other words, the site itself encourages multiple viewpoints in answers with extended detail. Isn't that, to an extent, a blog? I'm not trying to be negative, just trying to point out real concerns.

Comment: @Aarthi honestly, I would be very surprised if we saw the level of involvement and commitment necessary to make a blog viable, but one can always hope.... Regarding your second concern, I think we could find ways to mitigate that issue (by establishing guidelines, criteria, review processes, etc.), if we ever got to the point where a blog actually became a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

**Can** we start a parenting blog?
Yes, of course we can.

**Should** we start a blog ... now?
No, I don't think we should ... now.

I like blogs, I think they're great and it would be really cool to have a parenting blog. But a blog requires *a lot* of material and [we just don't have enough material right now](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4861/parenting) to keep a blog active. Actually, [we chatted about this more than a year ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1458353#1458353) and decided against it.

I'm not ready to invest any more effort into a parenting blog until a future point when the site is more mature and gets *more traffic and more content.* This meta question is well worded to start planning that.

Then ... not now. At the moment we should focus our energy on good content and more traffic.

Comment: +1 for more traffic! If we can't get enough questions to push our [metrics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4861/parenting) up to get us graduated, we don't have enough participation to maintain a blog.

Answer (score 1):

From managing the [Security blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com/) for a year now, I can tell you that although we have a strong and active community in meta and chat, we only got 6 contributors, 7 editors and 3 admins, and of those, less than half are regular so the load on the core team can be quite high.

Especially if you commit to a question of the week - I tend to drive folks quite hard on this, but still end up posting more than half of them myself, which in my opinion dilutes the value of the wider community.

On the plus side, some of our posts have driven vast amounts of traffic to the site...[this one](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/how-can-you-protect-yourself-from-crime-beasts-successor/) got us something like 10,000 views when linked on Reddit. So a very timely, hot-topic blog post can be a wonderful publicity device.

Like @Torben, I would say the community activity just isn't here yet. You need that core of users active in chat, on meta, and posting links on relevant websites to drive discussion, new members etc.